# Choppy canvas animation - EaselJS

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, createjs, easeljs, gsap

I'm trying to emulate the canvas element seen in [spire's](https://spire.com/) banner using EaselJS. But my animations are choppy both on chrome and firefox. Any help is appreciated. (Using EaselJS for the first time)

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>EaselJS</title>
    <style>
        body{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #spire-canvas{
            background: #333;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <canvas id="spire-canvas" width="1366" height="768"></canvas>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/EaselJS/0.8.0/easeljs.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){


            //INITIALIZATIONS
            var stage,
            particles = 10, 
            fps = 30, 
            viewportWidth = window.innerWidth, 
            viewportHeight = window.innerHeight,
            circles = [];

            function init(){
                stage = new createjs.Stage("spire-canvas");
                createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", refresh);
                createjs.Ticker.setFPS(fps);
                console.log("init fired");
            }

            function refresh(){
                for(var i = 0; i < particles; i++){
                    var circle = new createjs.Shape();
                    circle.graphics.beginFill('#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16))
                    .drawCircle(0, 0, (Math.random() * 10));
                    circle.x = circle.x + Math.random() * viewportWidth;
                    circle.y = (Math.random() * viewportHeight) + viewportHeight;
                    circle.alpha = 0.1 + Math.random() * 0.2;
                    stage.addChild(circle);
                    circles.push(circle);
                };
                for(var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++){
                    var item = circles[i];
                    var yy = item.y + Math.floor(Math.random() * (viewportHeight - 300)) * -1;

                    if(item.y < 300){
                        TweenLite.to(item, 1, {alpha: '0', ease: Power4.easeOut, onComplete: function(){
                            stage.removeChild(item);
                        }});
                    }

                    TweenLite.to(item, 10, {y: yy});
                };
                stage.update();
            }

            init();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your demo, which all will cause performance issues. The main thing it comes down to is that you are not properly using tweens, and not cleaning up items.

1. The main performance problem is that you are creating a new tween for each circle *every tick*. In your second loop, for each circle, you are calling `TweenLite.to(item, 10, {y: yy});`. This will create (and best case override) the tween for that object every single time, for each circle. At the rough rate you are making circles, there will be > 1000 circles at any given time. The best approach here is to move your overall move tween inside the loop where you make each circle, so it happens one time per circle.
2. The second issue with tweens is that you check if the circle is less than 300px, and tween it out (alpha) if it is. However since the circle is still moving while it fades, it means that each tick you are creating a NEW alpha tween for each circle. You should do this *one time* for each circle. You can do this by setting a flag on the element that it is fading out, so it doesn't happen more than once.
3. You are never removing circles from your `circles` array. This means your array is growing by 10 circles per tick ~ so about 300 circles per second. After 10 seconds you have 3000 circles, etc. With shapes, you are going to hit a performance max pretty quickly, even after resolving the issues with the tweens that I outlined above. When you remove from the stage, also remove from the array.
4. Graphics are slow. If you want something super performant, use images, or cached shapes. Your demo has random colors for each sprite, but the Spire demo does not. If you want some variety you could pre-cache a bunch of colors, and draw from an object pool of images, ideally in a SpriteSheet.

Overall, the overhead of Tweens is the biggest issue. You could probably refactor this to get better performance without using tweens, since the animations are pretty predictable.

Cheers,

Comment: Here is a quick sample with your code, and the tweens moved to the right place: http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/abLhozah/ -- I modified the threshold so that some of the items fade out, but none of them make it up high enough based on their initial value to be tweened out (they just stop). You should be able to get what you need from that sample.

Comment: I knew the problem was with the for loops inside ticks. Need to refer the documentations thoroughly. Anyhow thanks a bunch Lanny. Great help. Marked it as the answer.